# How to labelOnlyAB in venndiagram2sets?

Tags: venn-diagrams

I am trying to `labelOnlyAB={9}` in this code, but I cannot result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={18},labelOnlyB={24},
    labelOnlyAB={9},
    labelNotAB={45}]
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `labelAB={9}` instead of using `labelOnlyAB={9}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelOnlyA={18},labelOnlyB={24},
        labelAB={9},
        labelNotAB={45}]
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For fun with Asymptote.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1.5cm);
real d=.6;
transform t=shift(d,0), s=inverse(t);

draw(t*unitcircle,blue);
draw(s*unitcircle,magenta);
label(t*"24",E); label("B",t*(0,1),S);
label(s*"18",W); label("A",s*(0,1),S);

real a=2.2,b=1.3;
draw(box((-a,-b),(a,b)));
label("45",align=3NE,(-a,-b));

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```